# Python, Convert str to descriptors surf type

Tags: python, opencv, surf, descriptor

I want to read descriptors surf type from database, and uses it to compare to images using surf method, the problem is how to convert descriptors from string to ndarray array

```
#!/usr/bin/python
detector = cv2.SURF(400, 5, 5)
matcher = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_L2)
kp1, desc1 = detector.detectAndCompute(img1, None)     
cursor.execute(" SELECT * FROM visage WHERE id=%s", 1)
row = cursor.fetchone()
descriptor=row[6]
desc2=numpy.array(descriptor, dtype = numpy.float32).reshape((1,1))
kp_pairs = match_images(kp1, desc1 , kp2, desc2)
```

The error is:

pythonw -u "surf v2.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "surf v2.py", line 138, in 
    desc2=numpy.array(descriptor, dtype = numpy.float32).reshape((1,1))
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): [[  1.55181286e-03   1.55181286e-03  -2.10662147e-05 ...,   1.82572391e-03
    0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  7.83637588e-05   1.05563842e-03   3.83123639e-03 ...,   1.95306598e-03
    0.0000000

> Exit code: 1

Answer (score 0):

That kind of depends on how the strings look. Maybe the [`numpy.fromstring`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromstring.html) will work. Otherwise check how the string is created and use the inverse function.